# ratchet not working demo

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

I am working on ratchet php sockets. since i am new in sockets so i follow demo from [ratchet](http://socketo.me/) after follow the code i got the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Chat' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\chating\bin\chat-server.php on line 13
```

I copy all code but i still this error. i am going to paste the code of chat-server.php

```
<?php

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
              new HttpServer(
              new WsServer(
              new Chat()
            )
            ), 8080
);

$server->run();
```

Comment: is your chat class autoloadable?

Comment: how to autoload this chat class

Comment: yes i have autoload the chat class

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution after searching 
before run command

```
php bin/chat-server.php
```

first execute this command

```
composer dumpautoload
```